# How can i send the entered form data to my email adress?

Tags: php, database, email

How can i send a email to the person that enters his information in a php form. that his form data is saved. and also send an email to the webmaster with all the entered form data..
this is what i tried so far:

```
    mail($email, $subject, $autoreply);
    mail($default, $subject, $autoreply, $naam, $email, $telefoon_nr, $adres, $email_partner);
```

Comment: You need to create a single string for the body of the message. You can't just send it 15 variables and expect `mail` to know what to do with them.

Comment: [**Read the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) <= that's a [hyperlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a form.

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
<input type="number" name="age" id="age">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now your PHP file can handle it.

somefile.php:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first = $_POST['firstname']; $last = $_POST['lastname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $body = "First name: ".$first." Last name: ".$last." Age: ".$age;
    mail("example@example.com", "sample subject", $body);
}
?>
```

You can see the parameters of the `mail` function in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).